# How to add a button to the bottom of a page with a TextField on the page

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I have this page in Flutter :

[image]

Unfortunately, when I click on the `textfield` the keyboard shows up and the next button goes on top of the keybord, hiding the `textfield` :

[image]

I don't exactly understand why it behaves like this.

This is my code :

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jukebox/utils/ContainerImpl.dart';
import 'package:jukebox/utils/ElevatedButtonImpl.dart';
import 'package:jukebox/utils/TextImpl.dart';

class createAccount extends StatelessWidget {

  const createAccount({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ContainerImpl containerWidget = ContainerImpl(
        SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const <Widget> [
              TextImpl("Créer ton profil"),
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 120,
                backgroundImage:NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg') ,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: false,
                scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 300),
                cursorColor: Color.fromRGBO(233, 165, 208, 1),
                maxLength: 15,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(233, 165, 208, 0.9),
                    fontSize: 40
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    counterText: ""
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );

    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),

        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 350,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ElevatedButtonImpl(onPressed: () => {}, text: "Next")
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 24, 46, 1),
      appBar: appBar,
      body: containerWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to prevent this so I'm asking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the position of the button is fixed with the margin value.

```
return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 350,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ElevatedButtonImpl(onPressed: () => {}, text: "Next")
      ),
```

So, You can either give that more big margin or only when the keyboard is up.

If you want the previous one, just change margin value.

give this part( `margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10)`) more bigger one.

Or if you want the latter, try this.

Add code below

```
bool keyboardUp = false;

  _detextKeyboardUp() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0) {
      keyboardUp = true;
    } else {
      keyboardUp = false;
    }
  }
```

And also, add **_detextKeyboardUp()** method in build method
and change `margin:EdgeInsets.all(10)` to `margin:keyboardUp ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60) : EdgeInsets.all(10)`

```
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
    );
    _detextKeyboardUp();
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 350,
            margin:
                keyboardUp ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60) : EdgeInsets.all(10),
            // EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: Text("Next"))),

...
```

Didn't you want this way?
Do you want the button not to go up when keyboard up?

Then you had better to change the structure of the widget.

'Next' button will be in body of Scaffold not floatingActionButton.